# KVM is not enabled in host Error required compatibility check Virtualization Support

Tags: docker, kvm-virtualization

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3-amd64 in an Oracle VM. I followed the instructions in [Install Docker Engine on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and ran the command:

```
sudo apt install ./docker-desktop-4.22.1-amd64.deb
```

Everything seemed ok, but I got this error when I opened the docker desktop app:

[image: error image]

Can somebody help me in this matter?

Comment: It looks like you're installing Docker Desktop. Just Docker Engine (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) doesn't involve installing deb files and doesn't need virtualization.

Comment: Yes, first of all I downloaded Docker Engine so i could download Docker Desktop, but it that error was displayed.

My goal is download Docker Desktop. 

I have already enabled vt-d from Bios 

Thank for answering.